# Typescript typings for cloudboost (and use it with ionic2)

Tags: node.js, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, cloudboost

I wonder about any available typings for cloudboost.io https://github.com/CloudBoost/JavaScriptSDK. I have no experience with writing typings for existing js modules. I was trying to prepare any dumbest d.ts but with no success. i.e. using ionic2 and `npm install cloudboost` (also currently its required to separately `npm install fs`) I was trying to use `cloudboost.d.ts` like.

```
declare module "cloudboost" {}
```

or

```
declare var CB: any;
declare module "cloudboost" {
  export var CB: any;
}
```

the result is strange as `cloudboost` is included to ionic2 build (using it's webpack config) however when using i.e.

```
import * as CB from "cloudboost";
```

or similar `import` variants gives in return `CB` value of some socket.io object even if the inner webpack call seems to refer to proper `cloudboost` code. So even `any` dumb object would satisfy me for the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have typescript typing for CloudBoost JavaScript SDK yet, but you should be able to create one yourself.

Here's what I found after looking up on SO for this issue.

Here is a sample Node module written in TypeScript : https://github.com/basarat/ts-npm-module

Here is a sample TypeScript project that uses this sample module https://github.com/basarat/ts-npm-module-consume

Basically you need to :

compile with commonjs and declaration:true

generate a .d.ts file

And then

Have your ide read the generated .d.ts.

Let me know if this helps.

-Nawaz
CloudBoost.io Support Staff

Comment: Let me know if you can create one, and if you want to contribute to the repo. Send us the PR. :)

Here's the another link that might help : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages

Comment: thanks for hints! actually in the answer the original npm module is already a typescript one but I'll keep trying anyway. the MS resource sounds helpful though...